# Show that $\|b \|^2\ (\sin\theta)^2 = \min_x\ \|ax-b\|^2$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a,\ b$.

Tags: proof-writing, vectors, normed-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

> Show that $\|b \|^2\ (\sin\theta)^2 = \min_x\ \|ax-b\|^2$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a,\ b$. This is for vectors $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ \ {$0$}.

The second part of the question says: Interpret and illustrate (for $m = 2$) the result from the previous item. Hint: You might find it helpful to do part two before part one.

So I tried to illustrate $||b||^2(\sin\theta)^2$ but got stuck. I understand that the norm of a vector (at least in $2$ dimensions like in this case) is the hypotenuse of the right angle triangle made by the sides of the vector ($b_1$ and $b_2$ in this case). I'm not sure how to factor in the $(\sin \theta)^2$, or how exactly this whole thing would look if I tried to illustrate it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Start from the right side and think in 2d first. What spans Ax when x varies from minus infty to plus infty? Then put Ax=z . What is geometrically the vector z-b ? When is its norm (length) minimized?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are working in a Hilbert space or a finite-dimensional vector space $\mathcal{H}$ over $\mathbb{F}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ equipped with $\langle\_,\_\rangle$, a positive-definite  symmetric bilinear form (for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$) or Hermitian sesquilinear form (for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$).  The norm $\|\_\|$ is induced by $\langle\_,\_\rangle$.  In the case $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$, suppose that $\langle\_,\_\rangle$ is linear in the first argument and antilinear in the second argument.

Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero elements of $\mathcal{H}$.  Your job is to minimize the function $f:\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ given by
$$f(x):=\|ax-b\|^2\text{ for each }x\in\mathbb{F}\,.$$
Note that
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\langle ax-b,ax-b\rangle =\langle ax,ax\rangle-\langle ax,b\rangle-\langle b,ax\rangle+\langle b,b\rangle\\
&=\|a\|^2\,|x|^2-\langle a,b\rangle\,x-\overline{\langle a,b\rangle}\,\bar{x}+\|b\|^2
\\
&=\left|\|a\|x-\frac{\overline{\langle a,b\rangle}}{\|a\|}\right|^2+\left(\frac{\|a\|^2\,\|b\|^2-\big|\langle a,b\rangle\big|^2}{\|a\|^2}\right)
\,.\end{align}$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{F}$.  Ergo,
$$f(x)\geq \frac{\|a\|^2\,\|b\|^2-\big|\langle a,b\rangle\big|^2}{\|a\|^2} \text{ for every }x\in \mathbb{F}\,.$$
The equality holds if and only if
$$x=\frac{\overline{\langle a,b\rangle}}{\|a\|\,\|b\|}\,.$$

Finally, if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$, then the angle $\theta$ between $a$ and $b$ satisfies
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\overline{\langle a,b\rangle}}{\|a\|\,\|b\|}=\frac{\langle a,b\rangle}{\|a\|\,\|b\|}\,.$$
That is, $f(x)$ is minimized iff $x=\cos(\theta)$, so the minimum value of $f$ is
$$\frac{\|a\|^2\,\|b\|^2-\big|\langle a,b\rangle\big|^2}{\|a\|^2}=\frac{\|a\|^2\,\|b\|^2\big(1-\cos^2(\theta)\big)}{\|a\|^2}=\|b\|^2\,\sin^2(\theta)\,.$$

**P.S.**  The question tells you to deal with the $2$-dimensional case first probably because it suffices to assume that $\mathcal{H}$ is the $\mathbb{F}$-span of $a$ and $b$.  In which case, $\dim_\mathbb{F}(\mathcal{H})\in\{1,2\}$, depending on whether $a$ and $b$ are parallel (linearly dependent).  In particular, when $\dim_\mathbb{F}(\mathcal{H})\in\{1,2\}$ and $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$, you can embed $\mathcal{H}$ into a $2$-dimensional Euclidean space, which you should know how to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you explain why the equality holds if and only if $x = \frac{\bar{\langle a,b \rangle}}{||a|| ||b||}$? Also, why do we focus only on the $\frac{||a||^2 ||b||^2 - |\langle a,b \rangle |^2}{||a||^2}$ part? Thank you

Comment: Let $z$ denote $\|a\|\,x-\dfrac{\overline{\langle a,b\rangle}}{\|a\|}$.  Then, $z$ can take any complex value.  The function $f(x)$ is then equal to $$g(z)=|z|^2+c\,,$$ where $c:=\dfrac{\|a\|^2\,\|b\|^2-\big|\langle a,b\rangle\big|^2}{\|a\|^2}$.  Clearly, $|z|^2\geq 0$, so $f(x)=g(z)\geq c$.  But the minimum is achievable only when $|z|=0$, or $z=0$, which is equivalent to $x=\dfrac{\langle a,b\rangle}{\|a\|\,\|b\|}$.  So, the minimum is indeed $c$.